# Get current id of item without loop. Laravel, php

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent, orm

let's go to my problem. Suppose I have a table that is named **Hero** and now I want to get **HeroId** for the hero name **batman(unique)** for normal I will use a loop to check in the list hero if the hero that has a name is **Batman** so I got it. But with this way I must loop for too many times, this problem reminds me of the `Auth::user->id` the function has already been built by Laravel this function could get the id of any user that is currently on stage without using any loop. so What must I do to build like that?
Thanks, everyone.

```
public function get_name_byid($name_hero)
{
    return Hero::where('name_hero', $name_hero)->value('id');
}
```

```
Auth::user()->id
```

Comment: you want to get **batman id** is it ?

Comment: Auth::user() gets currently logged in user, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve. Try expanding the question a bit

Answer (score 2):

To get the `id` of your **data**, you have to do as such :

```
public function get_name_byid($name_hero)
{
    return Hero::where('name_hero', $name_hero)->select('id')->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try combining a `where` with a `firstOrFail`:

```php
Hero::where('name_hero', '=', $name_hero)->firstOrFail()->id
```

Using `firstOrFail` rather than `first` means that if the name of the hero isn't found a `ModelNotFound` exception will be thrown, which you could catch in your code.